# Kill program generated by subprocess with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, kill-process

This is a program created as an example for explanation.

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from worker import Worker


class TestUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.worker = Worker()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        run_btn = QPushButton("Run")
        run_btn.clicked.connect(self.run)

        kill_btn = QPushButton("Kill")
        kill_btn.clicked.connect(self.kill)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(run_btn, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(kill_btn, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def run(self):
        self.worker.run_command("calc.exe")

    def kill(self):
        self.worker.kill_command()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

**worker.py**

```py
import os
import signal
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run_command(self, cmd):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    def kill_command(self):
        # self.proc.kill() => Not working
        # self.proc.terminate() => Not working
        # os.kill(self.proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM) => Not working
```

I want to kill the program generated by subprocess when I click the kill button. In other words, I want to send a kill signal to the program like pressing CTRL+C.

And when the main PyQt5 program is terminated, I want the program generated by subprocess to terminate as well.

How can I do this?

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using Popen, or can [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) be used instead?

Comment: I'm a noob so I don't know about the QProcess. This is what I want to do.

Comment: 1. Run shell command and get the stdout, stderr in real-time.

Comment: 2. Run batch file and get the stdout, stderr in real-time, and can stop the file execution.

Comment: 3. Run other applications and can kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the method.

I used a `psutil` module.

This is not a built-in module. So you need to install it first.

> pip install psutil

And, now you can use this module like below.

```py
def kill_command(self):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if "calc" in proc.name().lower():
            os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```